# How do I set the background image of a react app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a react app and I want to add a background image to it.  I can't figure out how to do this and other stackoverflow answers aren't clear.  The image is named background.jpeg and it is saved in the same folder as App.js.  Here is the code that I would like to have a background.  Thanks!

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className = "top">
      <h1>Hit the button to generate a random top 25 all-time cd according to the Rolling  Stone</h1>
      </div>
    <div className =  "Outer">
    <div>
      <img src = {ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][0]} width = "400px" height = "400px"/>
      <p></p>
      <button onClick={this.RandomNumber}>Press me for a new album!</button>
      <p>Artist: {ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][1]} </p>
      <p>Album: {ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][2]} </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

and here is the css so far:

```
.Outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap a div around the content and then set the `backgroundImage` property in your render method. The rest of the relevant properties can be defined in your css class.

**Guideline:**

```
      <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][0]}`}} className="bg">
         <p></p>
         <button onClick={this.RandomNumber}>Press me for a new album!</button>
         <p>Artist: {ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][1]} </p>
         <p>Album: {ImageArray[this.state.WhichRecord][2]} </p>
     </div>
```

css:

```
.Outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also include an `<img />` tag with a fixed position and a background-size set to `cover`

`jsx`

```
import BackgroundImage from "./background.jpeg";

...

return (
    <div>
        <img src={BackgroundImage} />
        {/* Rest of app */}
    </div>
)
```

`css`

```
    ...
    img {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Gives a little more control over manipulation of the image...